# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type ''

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my view with viewModel:-

```
@model _24By7CallAndBPOPvtLtd.Models.JobDetailandApplyModel

                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.jobdetail)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.job_title
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.Job_ID })"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                                            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.Job_ID })"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
                        </table> 

                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.jobapplied)
                            {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_Account.Full_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Job_Det.job_title)
                            </td>

                            <td>  
                                <a href="/Content/CV/@item.User_CV.Cv_Path" target="_blank">Download</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        }

                        </table>
```

Here is my Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Test1()
        {
               var jobs=db.Job_Det.ToList();
                return View(jobs);
        }
public ActionResult Test2()
        {
            db.Job_Applied.ToList();
                return View("Test1");
        }
```

Here is my ViewModel:-

```
public class JobDetailandApplyModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Job_Det> jobdetail { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Job_Applied> jobapplied { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Job_Applied
    {
        public int JobApplied_ID { get; set; }
        public int Employeer_ID { get; set; }
        public int Job_ID { get; set; }
        public int User_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Cv_Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> status_Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime date_applied { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> time_applied { get; set; }
        public string timestamp_applied { get; set; }

        public virtual Employeer Employeer { get; set; }
        public virtual Job_Det Job_Det { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual User_CV User_CV { get; set; }
        public virtual User_Account User_Account { get; set; }
    }
```

What is the problem in this code?.i m passing two models in one view using viewModel, i need to display two lists in one view..

Comment: You are trying to assign your list to the whole model. You need to initialise the model and they assign values to each of the 2 lists

Comment: You are not passing your list to your view in the `Test2` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var jobs = db.Job_Det.ToList();

var jobApplied = db.Job_Applied.Include(x => x.Job_Det).ToList();

JobDetailandApplyModel model = new JobDetailandApplyModel() {
   jobdetail = jobs,
   jobapplied = jobApplied 

}

 return View(model);
```

also, not sure if this will make a difference but replace

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Job_Det.job_title)
```

with

```
@item.Job_Det.job_title
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, in the line..  **<td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Job_Det.job_title)
                            </td>**

Comment: are you sure your database is returning data?

Comment: i tried it..but still the same problem, please keep in mind that i use ur code in one method **Test1**, i comment the other method **Test2**

Comment: can you put your code for the two classes in the question?

Comment: What u mean? i did't understand

Comment: What does this class contain "Job_Applied"

Comment: Please check the updates for **Job_Applied** class in the Question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialise the model properly and assign values to each of the 2 properties. Change your controller to something like this:

```
var model = new JobDetailAndApplyModel();
model.jobdetail = db.Job_Det.ToList();
model.jobapplied = db.Job.Applied.ToList();
return view(model);
```

EDIT: the Test2 controller you have will not do much, when you pass it a string like that it just uses the view with a name the same as that string. It is passed no model, so you will get a null reference error. You will need something like this to make that one work:

```
return View("Test1", model);
```

Using the other code from above to create the model object.

Comment: that's more or less what i put ;)

Comment: yeah, looks like we were both typing at the same time.

Comment: Does it say what line the null reference is on? I imagine there is some data missing as there appear to be a lot of implied objects existing with no null checks. Does each JobApplied have a Job_Det and UserAccount oject as children?

Comment: when i put the debugger, it passes successfully from the controller and show counts of each, when passed to view, it gives null reference in **<td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Job_Det.job_title)
                            </td>**

Comment: Is the Job_Det table linked to the Job_Applied table? If not, you might try `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.job_title)` instead. It is hard to diagnose without seeing more of the code.

Comment: In your debugger, add a watch for `item.Job_Det` and see if there is any data there. If there isn't then you have some bad data.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is expecting a model of type JobDetailandApplyModel

Test1 provide a model of type

> List < Job_Det >

Test2 provides NO model